# In cakephp 2.4.6 Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS only two pages, What will be best approach ht-access or Cakephp Security Companent

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, redirect, ssl

I want to redirect two URL from HTTP to HTTPS  and after they redirect to secure URL and if they visit other pages again it will be again redirect to No-secure pages.

After checking so many example in Stackoverflow i am confused which one is best way to do it ht-access or Cakephp own security component.

### What I have

http://login.mydomain.com/Homes/index (HTTP)

http://login.mydomain.com/Homes/dashboard (HTTP)

http://login.mydomain.com/Resources/index (HTTP)

http://login.mydomain.com/Resources/add (HTTP)

### What I want

https://login.mydomain.com/Homes/index (HTTPS)

http://login.mydomain.com/Homes/dashboard (HTTP)

https://login.mydomain.com/Resources/index (HTTPS)

http://login.mydomain.com/Resources/add (HTTP)

so If i visit http://login.mydomain.com/Homes/index it will be re-ditected to secure index pages https://login.mydomain.com/Homes/index and if i got to dasboard pages from secure index pages it will again go to non-secure dashbord URL http://login.mydomain.com/Homes/dashboard (HTTP)

### What i have tried till now

### ht-access Code

# Add SSL on other pages

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Homes/index|Resources/index
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

## Remove SSL on other pages

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Homes/index|Resources/index
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Not working giving me 500 server error

also used this example

[Redirect HTTP to HTTPS for one page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133599/redirect-http-to-https-for-one-page)

But no effect either i am getting all pages HTTPS or getting pages without HTTPS but not like the way i want it.

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I have already tried few example like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133599/redirect-http-to-https-for-one-page  but they are not working for me .

Comment: Its is not good idea to just downgrade any question before understanding it , I am try different solution for days but not finding any good answer to my query then  i have posted my query over here.

Comment: Are these two URLs on different hosting account?

Comment: No, They are in same Hosting server

Comment: @Doitnow I suspect people have down voted your question because it is not clear what you have tried or what is not working for you. Show some example code of what you have attempted and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Also, please state the version of CakePHP you are developing with.

Comment: I am using Cakephp 2.4.6

Comment: @Doitnow: I am facing the same issue. May I know how you fixed it?

Comment: @dirtyhandsphp : I have used example given in Answer area and it has worked for me , If is is not working for you then please shear you code what you are trying, We will help you.

Comment: @Doitnow: I got the issue fixed. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this in Cake is to use the [Security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html). You can use its `requireSecure()` method to set the actions that require a SSL-secured request in your controller's `beforeFilter()`:-

```
class ResourcesController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Security');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Security->requireSecure('index');
    }
}
```

Using this you don't need to change things in `.htaccess` as Cake will be handling the redirects for you.

Comment: Ok,  I have use the code you have given but it is giving me this error : The request has been black-holed
Error: The requested address '/Homes/index' was not found on this server.

Comment: It looks like this is another issue. Take a look at these StackOverflow questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002685/the-request-has-been-black-holed-cakephp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266831/the-request-has-been-black-holed.

Comment: I have checked  both the links but Not much help but during my test i have found very wired issue , just for checking i have deleted everything in my index ctp file so that i can check security is working or not  but even though i am getting "black-holed" error and i have disable the layout but error is there.

Comment: I have created a new function in Homes Controller with blank content but it is also giving me same error, Any suggestion what can cause it