# croogo 2 Request blackholed due to "auth" violation

Tags: mysql, cakephp, croogo

I have a problem with my old website. Now I try to move it to new server (php5.6) and when i try to save data I have error:

> Request blackholed due to "auth" violation.

I serach the place whose do it this error:

```
                if ($this->Node->saveWithMeta($this->request->data)) {
        Croogo::dispatchEvent('Controller.Nodes.afterAdd', $this, array('data' => $this->request->data));
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('%s has been saved', $type['Type']['title']), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
        if (isset($this->request->data['apply'])) {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $this->Node->id));
        } else {
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
```

I think error do function saveWithMeta(). This function view like:

```
public function saveWithMeta(Model $model, $data, $options = array()) {
    $data = $this->_prepareMeta($data);
    return $model->saveAll($data, $options);
}
```

Can I replace/edit this function so that it starts to work?

edit

```
if (!$db->create($this, $fields, $values)) {
                    $success = $created = false;
                } else {
                    $created = true;
                }
```

These lines cause an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The request has been black-holed - CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002685/the-request-has-been-black-holed-cakephp)

Comment: unfortunately this is not it

Comment: can you look as my edit? I try to edit Cake/model.php and this lines get my the error